# String replace Hash using regex with special condition (lookahead / lookbehind)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, replace, v8

Lets stay I have the following list of string, in JavaScript (NodeJS) I want to apply a regex one at a time and replace the hash between `.` and `.`, but I don't want to replace the word, `.style`. or `.bundle.` or .`chunk.` and it should also work to replace the hash in the case where there is no preceding dots.

```
// hash starts with number
/css/app.style.7fef363d5a8c4ef2458c.css
/css/app.bundle.7fef363d5a8c4ef2458c.css
/css/app.chunk.7fef363d5a8c4ef2458c.css
/css/app.7fef363d5a8c4ef2458c.css
/css/loading-animation.7fef363d5a8c4ef2458c.css

// hash starts with letter
/css/app.style.b3bcb606396f0c96623a.css
/css/app.bundle.b3bcb606396f0c96623a.css
/css/app.chunk.b3bcb606396f0c96623a.css
/css/app.b3bcb606396f0c96623a.css

// no preceeding dot separated name before the hash
/css/loading-animation.b3bcb606396f0c96623a.css
/css/app.b3bcb606396f0c96623a.js

// It should not affect items without a hash
/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.svg
```

The result should be

```
// hash starts with number
/css/app.style.css
/css/app.bundle.css
/css/app.chunk.css
/css/app.css
/css/loading-animation.css

// hash starts with letter
/css/app.style.css
/css/app.bundle.css
/css/app.chunk.css
/css/app.css

// no preceeding dot separated name before the hash
/css/loading-animation.css
/css/app.js

// It should not affect items without a hash
/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.svg
```

I tried hard and the closest I got was this

```
 const manifest = {};
 stats.assets.map(asset => asset.name)
    .sort()
    .forEach((file) => {
       let regEx = /\.(?!(?:[A-Za-z]))(([^.]*))\./gi
       let passTest = regEx.test(file);
       let key = file.replace(regEx, '.');
       console.log(file, passTest, key);
       manifest[key] = file;
    });
```

But that only replaces the hash starting with the number, and ignores all the rest.

I also tried `/\.(?!(?:[A-Za-z]))(([^.]*))\./gi;` but that just replaced the first occurrence of `.something.`

I also had no luck with negative lookbehinds (it is a new feature in JS according to [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-regexp-proposals#lookbehinds) and [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/es-regexp-proposals#lookbehinds))

What is the proper regex for this?

Comment: `\.[^.]+(?=\.(?:css|js))`?

Comment: @ctwheels Thanks! That also worked, for when I have only .css and .js files. In the case I have .png and unknown file extension, it would need a little modification

Comment: You can use `[^.]+\.(?=[^.]+$)` (variation from my above), but at that point it's just Joseph's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
[^.]+\.(?=[^.]+$)
```

It looks for any non-period characters followed by a period (`[^.]+\.`) followed by (using a lookahead) a series of non-period characters (`[^.]+`) and an end-of-line (`$`).

https://regex101.com/r/5QfED2/1

Comment: Wow, that was quick. THANKS!! I spent hours and you did it in a couple minutes lol.

Comment: I just had to add `\.` in the front so that when my string replace comes along, it replaces boths `.`'s and the hash with the new `.`  I'll accept your answer soon, its got a cooldown.

Comment: @TetraDev why don't you just replace the single dot version with an empty string instead of replacing both dots with a dot?

Comment: @ctwheels Good point, I didn't think of that. I will do that instead.

Comment: Actually, this has a side effect. Now it also replaces items that have no hash, such as `/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot` into `eot`. Can this be modified to not apply to items that don't have a hash?

Comment: @TetraDev Sure.  Here's a fork: https://regex101.com/r/gY7w7f/1.  All it needs is to clarify that `[^.]` should not include newlines either with `[^.\n]`.  It would be better if we could use a lookbehind to ensure that there are two period characters, but JS doesn't support that.  Checking to make sure no newline characters are matched should adequately simulate that.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That is brilliant and genius at the same time. Thanks again!!